Column wise minimum with nan value
I have below dataframe and I want to compute column-wise min value
import pandas as pd
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,3,4], 'col2' : [-3, np.nan, 4, 4]})
dat1.min(axis = 1, numeric_only = True)

However for the 2nd row, I was expecting nan value because col2 has nan, however I get 2 which is the value of col1.
Could you please help to correct above code.

By default the NaNs are ignored, you should use skipna=False (see the documentation of min):
dat1.min(axis=1, numeric_only=True, skipna=False)

Output:
0   -3.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    4.0
dtype: float64

